# Accessing other languages website

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I added new language to my website **ar-AE** if i want to access the Arabic website i will append **"ar-AE"** after the site URL :

> http://mywebsite.com/ar-AE/aboutus

But I want it to work with only **/ar**

> http://mywebsite.com/ar/aboutus

how i can do that with sitecore ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `ar` as new Language instead of ar-AE. same as the default `en` or Danish language, da.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own implementation of `LinkProvider` (to generate links with `ar` instead of `ar-ae` and your own implementation of `LanguageResolver` processor (to get the Language from the request).

1. LinkProvider - create your own LinkProvider class inheriting from `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider` class and override `GetItemUrl` method. Register it in the configuration instead of the default provider. More details here: [Custom Link Provider for Sitecore](https://keeplearningandsharing.wordpress.com/tag/custom-link-provider/)
2. LanguageResolver - create your own LanguageResolver class inheriting from `HttpRequestProcessor` and add it to `httpRequestBegin` pipeline after or instead of the original resolver. More details here: [Overriding Sitecore's Logic to Determine the Context Language](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2010/11/overriding-sitecores-logic-to-determine-the-context-language.aspx)